# SVG animation issue. Not getting as desired

Tags: html, xml, animation, svg, path

I need a small help to fit this animation : http://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ByRzOV

to this between M and T :

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 376 56.6" enable-background="new 0 0 376 56.6" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#232527" d="M345.8,53.3C345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-21.7-44c-0.7-1.5-0.1-3.3,1.4-4
 c1.5-0.7,3.3-0.1,4,1.4l19,38.6l19.2-38.6c0.7-1.5,2.5-2.1,4-1.3c1.5,0.7,2.1,2.5,1.3,4l-21.9,44C348,52.6,347,53.3,345.8,53.3z
  M274.5,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.7,1.3-3,3-3s3,1.3,3,3v44C277.5,51.9,276.1,53.3,274.5,53.3z M205,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-41
 h-19c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3h44c1.7,0,3,1.3,3,3s-1.3,3-3,3h-19v41C208,51.9,206.7,53.3,205,53.3z M30.5,53.2
 C30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-16-32.5v31.1c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.4,1-2.6,2.3-2.9
 C9.6,3,11,3.6,11.6,4.9l19,38.6L49.8,4.9c0.6-1.2,2-1.9,3.4-1.6c1.4,0.3,2.3,1.5,2.3,2.9v44c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3V18.9
 L33.2,51.6C32.7,52.6,31.7,53.2,30.5,53.2z"/>
</svg>
```

I have tried alot and played around but did not get success. Please help.
Or is there any other way to have this type of Circle animation in SVG. I tried to create  as well but did not work. Also Is it possible without css and js?

Thank you in advance. Really appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: animate the stroke-dasharray. There's lots of existing questions and answers about that on this site.

Comment: Had tried all.. stroke-dasharray works with css/js...can we do without that?

Comment: Maybe, what way do you want to do it?

Comment: I want to add the <path> to generate the arcs and animate like the link I showed. Tried with <g> group of paths as well but not worked. Is there any other way to just get the SVG from the link I showed and fit that same in between M and T?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with CSS animations: https://jsfiddle.net/3o9msftL/1/, though it doesn't quite have the same easing, and seems to be more CPU-intensive than the GreenSock JS animations (which I haven't yet delved into).

Basically I added a circle that looks like this:

```
<circle cx="120" cy="29" r="23" 
        stroke-width="6" stroke="#000" fill="none" 
        style="animation: dash 5s infinite; 
               animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955); 
               transform: rotate(-90deg) /* else it starts on the right side */; 
               transform-origin: 120px 29px"
        stroke-dasharray="150, 150" stroke-linecap="round"/>
```

Those dimensions because they seemed to fit with the rest of your SVG, and I believe the 150,150 values because it's roughly 2πr (i.e. the circumference).  Then in the CSS, I added the following CSS:

```
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -300;
  }
}
```

300 being the sum of the dash arrays (or is it double of the stroke?), and negative for the clockwise direction.